# What account should my self hosted service run as for ntlm passthrough to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, owin

I have created a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API service (using OWIN) that I am running as a Windows service. I want the user to have the option of using Windows authenticated users in SQL Server and I would like the browser/user-agent accessing the (REST API) web service to pass through the NTLM user info so that they get Windows authenticated access to the SQL Server database.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: The standard way is to authenticate the user in your web application, and do role-based authorization yourself for actions your service can perform. If you can obtain the user's password, you can log them on separately and run a helper process that will perform database actions on behalf of the user, but that raises other security concerns. What *isn't* possible is to directly impersonate the user in your service for purposes of accessing the database, because ADO.NET doesn't support impersonation. ([Most things don't](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533/).)

Comment: Right, so the account the service runs as is the account that will be used to access the DB? Also, I don't have a web application that does authentication per se since it's a RESTful API service. I have looked into OAuth and that looks like the direction I'd be heading if I starting doing role-based access.

Comment: Yes. Recommended practice for that is to use a dedicated account (local or domain) rather than machine accounts.